# not able to use printf in cuda kernel function

Tags: cuda, printf

It seems that `printf` doesn't work inside the Kernel of a cuda code

```
#include "Common.h"
#include<cuda.h>
#include <stdio.h>

__device__ __global__ void Kernel(float *a_d , float *b_d ,int size)
{
    int idx = threadIdx.x ;
    int idy = threadIdx.y ;
    //Allocating memory in the share memory of the device
    __shared__ float temp[16][16];

    //Copying the data to the shared memory
    temp[idy][idx] = a_d[(idy * (size+1)) + idx] ;


    printf("idx=%d, idy=%d, size=%d\n", idx, idy, size);


    for(int i =1 ; i<size ;i++) {
            if((idy + i) < size) { // NO Thread divergence here
                    float var1 =(-1)*( temp[i-1][i-1]/temp[i+idy][i-1]);
                    temp[i+idy][idx] = temp[i-1][idx] +((var1) * (temp[i+idy ][idx]));
            }
            __syncthreads(); //Synchronizing all threads before Next iterat ion
    }
    b_d[idy*(size+1) + idx] = temp[idy][idx];
}
```

when compiling, it says:

```
 error: calling a host function("printf") from a __device__/__global__ function("Kernel") is not allowed
```

The cuda version is 4

Comment: Do I understand correctly you are trying to print some text *from a GPU*? I'm not surprised it isn't supported.

Comment: yes. I want to check some variables

Comment: I'm afraid this won't do. You may be successful with an emulator but I don't expect this to be possible with the real device.

Comment: You know, the GPU code might run several times in parallel, the GPU bus isn't really designed to transfer control from the GPU, ... . Perhaps writing to a buffer and reading the buffer from CPU?

Comment: Write to an offscreen buffer (each function to its own pixel of the buffer) and print it from the CPU?

Comment: printf from kernels is supported on CC 2.0 and greater.  If you have a cc 2.0 or newer GPU, compile with -arch=sm_20 and the error should go away

Comment: As an addendum to what Robert said: device-side printf requires use of the ABI, so code containing printf() cannot be compiled with -abi=no. Also, you must include the stdio header file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quoting the CUDA Programming Guide "[Formatted output is only supported by devices of compute capability 2.x and higher](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#formatted-output)". See the programming guide for additional information.

Devices of compute capability < 2.x can use cuPrintf.

If you are on a 2.x and above device and you are trying to use printf make sure you have specified arch=sm_20 (or higher). The default is sm_10 which does not have sufficient features to support printf.

NVIDIA offers three source level debuggers for CUDA. You may find these more useful than printf for inspecting variables.
 - Nsight Visual Studio Edition CUDA Debugger
 - Nsight Eclipse Edition CUDA Debugger
 - cuda-gdb

Comment: since you are here this is really stupid that you can't debug on the same device that xorg uses. just saying - no offense (EDIT: ok not stupid but annoying)

Answer (score 4):

You need to use cuPrintf, as in [this example](http://www.cs.usfca.edu/~peter/cs625/code/cuprintf_test.cu).  Note that printf is a pretty limited way of debugging, the Nsight or Nsight eclipse edition IDEs are much nicer.

Comment: Sorry - any of a number of cuPrintf() examples work, e.g. https://code.google.com/p/stanford-cs193g-sp2010/wiki/TutorialHelloWorld , although now devices of compute capability 1.x are getting harder to find.