# I get an error when I try to use printf() in a kernel

Tags: cuda

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and a GTX480 with compute capability 2.0.

I have tried setting sm to 2.0, but when I attempt to use printf() in a kernel, I get:

> error : calling a host function("printf") from a __device__/__global__
>   function("test") is not allowed

This is my code:

```
#include "util\cuPrintf.cu"
#include <cuda.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

__global__ void test (void)
{
  printf("Hello, world from the device!\n");
}

void main(void)
{
    test<<<1,1>>>();
    getch();
}
```

I find a example here: "CUDA_C_Programming_Guide" 'page _106' "B.16.4 Examples"
at last,it is work for me :D thank you.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include <conio.h>

// printf() is only supported
// for devices of compute capability 2.0 and higher

  #if defined(__CUDA_ARCH__) && (__CUDA_ARCH__ < 200)
      #define printf(f, ...) ((void)(f, __VA_ARGS__),0)
  #endif


__global__ void helloCUDA(float f)
{
    printf("Hello thread %d, f=%f\n", threadIdx.x, f);
}

int main()
{
    helloCUDA<<<1, 5>>>(1.2345f);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Add `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` after the kernel call. Include only `iostream` and `cuda_runtime.h`.

Comment: @sgar91: you need  `cstdio` for kernel printf

Comment: @talonmies.. `iostream` is a superset of `cstdio`. I am able to use `printf` by including `iostream`.

Comment: Since English is not your first language, it would be much appreciated if you would use a spell checker in the future.

Comment: I also added "cudaDeviceSynchronize()" still have a error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use `printf` in kernel code, you have to do three things:

1. make sure that `cstdio` or `stdio.h` are included in the kernel compilation unit. CUDA implements kernel `printf` by overloading, so you must include that file
2. Compile your code for compute capability 2.x or 3.x and run it on a supported GPU (so pass something like `-arch=sm_20` to nvcc or the IDE equivalent in Visual Studio or Nsight Eclipse edition)
3. Ensure that the kernel has finished running by including an explicit or implicit synchronization point in your host code (`cudaDeviceSynchronize` for example).

Comment: This is a picture from my settings.http://jagvar.persiangig.com/image/2013-02-12_202138.jpg

Answer (score 1):

You are probably compiling for an architecture that does not support printf(). By default the project is compiled for compute architecture 1.0. To change this, in VS open the project properties -> CUDA C/C++ -> Device and change the "Code Generation" property to "compute_20,sm_20".

You do not need `#include "util\cuPrintf.cu"`. Please see [this](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#formatted-output) for details on how to use printf and how to flush the output so you actually see the result.

Comment: Thank you very much, at "CUDA_C_Programming_Guide" 'page _106' "B.16.4 Examples" I find my answer.      #if defined(__CUDA_ARCH__) && (__CUDA_ARCH__ < 200)
      #define printf(f, ...) ((void)(f, __VA_ARGS__),0)
  #endif

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting that error, it probably means that your GPU does not have Compute capability 2.x or higher.  [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13315787/not-able-to-use-printf-in-cuda-kernel-function) goes into more detail on what your options are for printing inside a kernel function.

Comment: It is specified in the question that OP has Compute 2.0 device.

Comment: Ah, it's in the title and I skimmed over that bit.  Sorry!

Comment: I checked here, GTX 480 compute capability is 2.0 https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus